# distance between any two nodes in a graph(based on edges between them)

Tags: data-structures, graph, depth-first-search

The below code in c++ is to find the distance between any two nodes in a graph but there is some logical error where I tried to find but can't. Everything seems to be perfect but I can say that there is something wrong with a `break` inside `if` condition inside for loop which is inside `while(s.!empty())`.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int find_distance(int link[100][100],int start,int dest,int n,int e)
{
    start=start-1;
    dest=dest-1;
    if(start==dest)return 0;
    int visited[100];
    int distance;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        visited[i]=0;
    }
    stack<int>s;
    int k;s.push(start);
    visited[start]=1;
    bool found=false;
    int count =0;
    while(!s.empty())
    {
        k=s.top();
        int i;

        int check_point=1;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(link[k][i]==1 && visited[i]!=1)
            {
                s.push(i);
                count ++;
                check_point=0;
                if(i==dest)
                {
                    cout<<"found";
                    found=true;             
                }
            break;
            }
        }
        if(check_point==1)
        {
            s.pop();
            count--;
        }
        if(found)break;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    int n,e,a,b;
    int link[100][100];
    cout<<"enter the number of vertices and edges";
//  cin>>n>>e;
n=5;e=4;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
            link[i][j]=0;
            else
            link[i][j]=INT_MAX;
            cout<<link[i][j]<<"             ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    int input[4][2]={{1,2},{1,3},{2,4},{2,5}};
    for(int i=0;i<e;i++)
    {
        a=input[i][0];
        b=input[i][1];
        link[a-1][b-1]=1;
        link[b-1][a-1]=1;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            cout<<link[i][j]<<"              ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    while(true) {
        cout<<endl<<"enter the starting point .. ";
        int start;
        cin>>start;
        int dest;
        cout<<endl<<"enter the destination point .. ";
        cin>>dest;

        int distance = find_distance(link,start,dest,n,e);
        cout<<endl<<"distance is "<<distance;   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! As such, your question is too broad and does not constitute a reproducible question that could help other people with a similar problem. You'll see that StackOverflow is not a place where you ask people to debug your program - aim for targeted questions once you have narrowed down your question. Best of luck with your bug!

Comment: The code does not record the shortest distance (SD) detected so far between any two given nodes. You never set `visited` to any other value but `0`, so this variable is moot. SD computation is based on having a 'front' of vertices whose SDs to the start node have already been computed. This implies that all incoming edges of these vertices must have been visited (as any of these may be on the shortest path) before you start checking on their successors, can't see that your code ascertains that. Finally, your data structure is the adjacency matrix which is inefficient for sparse graphs.

Comment: please add programming-language tag. Aso : dfs tag is not the right one here:  **"DFS is a distributed filesystem from Microsoft. Note: for questions about depth-first search, please use the depth-first-search tag. **NOT to be confused** with [depth-first-search"**